# Why doesnt the align-self: flex-end css property doesnt work on flex div?

Tags: css, reactjs

i want to align the click me button to the left of the div containing it.

below is my code,

```
render = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Body>
                <span>Title</span>
                <Description/>
                <ChildComponent/>
            </Body>
            <Actions>
                {((condition1 && !condition2) || !condition1) && (
                    <ActionText>
                        Hide 
                    </ActionText>
                )}
                {condition1 ? (
                    condition2 ? (
                        <ButtonLink href="dddd">Click me</ButtonLink> // i want this                              //to be displayed at the extreme right of Actions div
                    ) : (<ButtonLink href="ee">Add</ButtonLink>)
                ) : null}
            </Actions>
        </Wrapper>
    }

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;

 const Body = styled.div`
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
 `;

  const Actions = styled.div`
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
  `;

   const ButtonLink = styled.a`
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
   `;
```

i want the click me button to be displayed at the extreme right of Actions div. i have tried to use align-self: flex-end to the ButtonLink click me and it doesnt work.

However adding margin-left to ButtonLink click me moves it.

i want to use flex-end. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `align-self: flex-end;` will only align something vertical (upp and down so to speak). It is a bit hard when not having a visual but try giving your Actions a `flex-end`

```
  const Actions = styled.div`
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: flex-end;
  `;
```